# SoftLayer API - Cancel Portable Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have successfully ordered Portable Storage.
I also can attach and detach the disk image from the instance.
After I get my VSI cancelled is there any way I can also cancel Portable Storage via REST call?

Answer (score 0):

Practically all the Softlayer resources have a billing item, if you want to cancel the resource you have to cancel the billing item.

The service for portable storages has a method to return the associated billing item to the the portable storage:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Disk_Image/getBillingItem

Once you have the billingItem you can cancel it using:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService

if that method does not work try with:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService

I hope it helps regards